# Format the string "DDMMYY HH:MM" into "YY-MM-DD HH:MM"

Tags: c++, linux

I want to convert the string "DDMMYY HH:MM"  into  "YY-MM-DD HH:MM" using boost library or any API.

Thanks,

Comment: I assume you are having some specific problem with what you have already attempted? You should show the code, along with a detailed description of the problem, including your expected output and the output you actually see.

Answer (score 3):

The best option would of course be to generate the RIGHT string to begin with, but I wouldn't work hard to get a "library" to do this, as it's really excessive...

Just something like this

```
std::string input = "DDMMYY HH:MM";

std::string output = input.substr(4, 2) + "-" + // YY-
                     input.substr(2, 2) + "-" + // MM-
                     input.substr(0, 2) +     // DD
                     input.substr(6);          //  HH:MM ("the rest")
```

Wrap it as a function `reformat_date` with a bit of explanation first.